# matlab Array dimensions must match for binary array op

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing

i have been stuck on this problem for quite a while now, i am trying to make a code in matlab that looks through a wally crowd picture and tries to find wally by comparing it to a picture of wally using the code from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fthnVKL0ZuQ&list=PL6FZQoc1x2Kl7jYc_R713P0yZaapnPqsh&index=9) but it keeps repeating the same exact error message, ive tried several things to solve but none seem to work, ive even tried pasting the code in chatgpt to see if he finds it and nothing
anyway, enough of me rambling, this is the code

```
wallyCrowd = imread('wallyCrowd.jpg');
wally = imread('wally.jpg');

figure(1); clf;
subplot(1,2,1)
imshow(wallyCrowd)
title('Wally Multidao')
xlabel('u - [pixels]')
ylabel('v - [pixels]')
axis on

subplot(1,2,2)
imshow(wally)
title('wally')
xlabel('u - [pixels]')
ylabel('v - [pixels]')
axis on

similarity = imageFilter(wallyCrowd,wally,@zncc);

%% rest of the code
```

this is the zncc function

```
function s = zncc(I1, I2)

    %% Calculate numerator and denominator
    I1_ = mean(I1,'all');
    I2_ = mean(I2,'all');

    snum = sum((I1-I1_).*(I2-I2_),'all');
    sden = sqrt(sum((I1-I1_).^2, 'all') .* sum((I2- I2_).^2, 'all'));

    %% Return result
    s = snum / sden;
end
```

this is the image filter function

```
function g = imageFilter(f, T, metric)

    %% Convert f and T to a double
    f = double(f);
    T = double(T);

    %% Initialise output
    % HINT: ensure it's a double
    g = zeros(size(f));

    %% Interpret data
    % Hint: Store the size of f and T as useful variables
    [fv, fu] = size(f);
    [Tv, Tu] = size(T);

    dv = floor((Tv - 1)/2);  % Use floor to ensure an integer value
    du = floor((Tu - 1)/2);  % Use floor to ensure an integer value

    %% Create Padded image
    fp = padarray(f, [dv, du], 0, 'both');

    %% Create variables which hold the relative indices
    v = -dv:dv;
    u = -du:du;

    %% Perform convolution
    if nargin == 2
        metric = @(a, b) sum(a .* b, 'all');
    end

    for i = 1:fv
        for j = 1:fu
            patch = fp(i:i+2*dv, j:j+2*du); % Ajuste aqui
            g(i, j) = metric(patch, T);
        end
    end
end
```

and this, is the error message that i keep recieving

```
Array dimensions must match for binary array op.

Error in zncc (line 10)
    snum = sum((I1-I1_).*(I2-I2_),'all');

Error in imageFilter (line 41)
            g(i, j) = metric(patch, T);

Error in encontrar (line 34)
similarity = imageFilter(wallyCrowd,wally,@zncc);
```

if its relevant, im using the R2018b version of matlab, i know that the error message is telling me where the problem is but the issue is that i dont know what to do here

Answer (score 1):

i just solved the problem, but i will post my answer here anyway in case someone else has the same, the problem was that the images i was trying to process where not grayscaled, zncc requires them to be in grayscale, so by adding this to the moment i open them

```
%% TODO: Read input image: "wallyCrowd.jpg" from file.
wallyCrowd = imread('wallyCrowd.jpg');
wallyCrowd = rgb2gray(wallyCrowd);
%% TODO: Read the template from file.
wally = imread('wally.jpg');
wally = rgb2gray(wally);
```

the code worked no problem